# plot of cumulative function of a discrete variable in r

Tags: r, function, cumsum, cdf

I want to do a plot of cumulative function of a discrete variable  in  r like this

[image: cdf]

this is my code

```
# Créer la fonction cumulative

F <- stepfun(c(1, 2, 3), c(0, 0.5, 0.875, 1))

plot(F, do.points = FALSE, col = "blue", type = "s", lwd = 2,
 xlab = "x", ylab = "F(x)", main = "Fonction de répartition")
```

but it is not the same

this is the results of my code

[image]

Comment: Add `verticals=FALSE` to the `plot()` call according to the `?plot.stepfun` documentation.

Comment: Thanks, how can I add the brackets please?